# Historical Claims Against Jesus Christ's Existence?

Tags: ancient-history, christianity, 1st-century, jesus

According to [this article](http://reknew.org/2008/01/corroborating-historical-evidence-of-the-new-testament/), "no one in the ancient world ever flatly denied that Jesus performed miracles – let alone that he existed." Is this historically accurate? **Are there any claims in history from the first century primarily** (although maybe a few centuries afterward may be allowed in the definition of "the ancient world") **that deny Jesus Christ existed?**

There is historical evidence that supports his existence, as I said in the comments below:

> There are ancient historical documents that refer to Jesus. Some attempt to explain away certain things related to him, but none that I have found claim he never existed. For example there is a letter by Justin Martyr to the Roman Emperor Antonius Pius, in which he cites the official ‘Acts of Pilate’ as corroboration for the crucifixion account. The first century historian Thallus mentions the darkness that the Gospels speak of and tries to explain it as an eclipse. He doesn't make reference to Jesus as far as I know.

Comment: A more reasonable question would be about the sources which claim his existence. Are there any, besides the Gospels, which were written long after his presumed death?

Comment: @Alex There are ancient historical documents that refer to Jesus. Some attempt to explain away certain things related to him, but none that I have found claim he never existed. For example there is a letter by Justin Martyr to the Roman Emperor Antonius Pius, in which he cites the official ‘Acts of Pilate’ as corroboration for the crucifixion account. The first century historian Thallus mentions the darkness that the Gospels speak of and tries to explain it as an eclipse. He doesn't make reference to Jesus as far as I know.

Comment: Is there any source stating that [Biggus Dickus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPGb4STRfKw) did not exist?

Comment: @SJuan76 who is "Dickus Maximus"?

Comment: @AChildofGod corrected the name and added a link. Thing is, Christianity did not became relevant until way after the supposed death of Jesus, so the lack of claims against its existence is in no way proof of anything. It would have make no sense for any serious registrar to document that "Jesus did not exist" as to claim that "Biggus Dickus did not exist"; both would have been largely irrelevant at the time these facts could have been contrasted.

Comment: @SJuan76 What do you mean by "Christianity did not become relevant until way after the supposed death of Jesus"? Read my comment to Alex. There is evidence that supports his existence - especially his death. I am curious if there is anyone claiming he didn't exist.

Comment: @SJuan76 - Not sure what you mean by "way after", but the Roman government considered Christianity relevant enough to wage war against it 30 years after the establishment of the church

Comment: Mark Anthony Songer - the Roman government never aged war against Christianity.  To do so they would have had to consider Christianity a foreign government. Instead various Roman officials sought to punish Christians as subjects of the empire accused of various alleged crimes.

Comment: @MAGolding nevertheless, Christianity was considered relevant enough to be seen as criminals worthy of mass execution and imprisonment.

Comment: MAGolding - "wage war" is, in this case, an idiom meaning "to take aggressive action against" and has nothing to do with their status as a sovereign nation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions speak louder than words, they say.

In the years following Jesus' death, the persecution against Christians came primarily from the Jews as chronicled in the book of Acts (4:3-22, 5:17-42, 6:8-8:1, 8:3, 9:2, 9:23-24, 20:19, 23:12-14, 12:1-5, 13:44-51, 14:5-6, 14:19-20, 16:16-24, 17:1-15, 18:12-17, 19:23-41, 19:27-28:30). The interesting thing about this time period (from AD33 to AD60-ish) is there is no record of claims against the existence of Jesus. There are numerous arguments against claims made by Gnostic cults (1 John, 1 Peter, and others) and one possible argument made in defense of the resurrection (1 Cor 15:12-19). However, nowhere in the New Testament is the existence of Jesus defended.

By AD64, only 30-ish years after the crucifixion of Jesus, Nero began wide-spread persecution of Christians. During this time, countless hirtory books and ancient documents record Christians being imprisoned, tortured, and killed for their faith and their refusal to declare the emperor as god (and any other charges that could be trumped up against them such as setting Rome on fire). If, as some scholars believe, John wrote Revelation during the time of Domitian it could be a chronicling of the persecution of Christians by Rome. Polycarp, Irenaeus and other early Second Century church fathers also document the persecution during those times.

My point about the period of Roman persecution is this: There are not records of attempts to prove the Christians wrong. Rather than just killing them and thereby solidifying their faith, how much easier would it have been to issue proclamations that Jesus did not rise from the dead, or that He was living in Gaul with his prostitute wife, or that He never existed? This persecution began a whole generation after the death of Jesus and establishment of the church. Even a campaign of disinformation would have made sense. But even during this time that the eradication of Christianity became a priority of State we have no indicators that denials of any of the claims made by Christians concerning Jesus were false.

To me, this silence on the part of Rome and, before that, the Jewish authorities, is strong evidence.

Comment: I remember reading that the Jews had to make up a story about the disciples stealing the body to account for the missing body of Jesus

Comment: Do you have a citation for that? I remember being told it was a possibility that they manufactured such a story, but I do not recall seeing the story or a response to it anywhere.

Comment: I remember reading about it in a certain article. It mentioned that a few historians had mentioned this. I can't remember which article I had read said it, so I looked to Wikipedia for some answers. Here is one: Martyr, Justin. *Dialogue with Trypho*, Chapter CVIII.

Comment: Also, here is an article from Answers in Genesis that mentions this. It isn't the one I had read, but nevertheless it discusses it. https://answersingenesis.org/jesus-christ/resurrection/the-body-was-moved/ It mentions Tertullian discussing this as well as Martyr

Comment: The Answers in Genesis article provides a quote from Justin Martyr: "… yet you not only have not repented, after you learned that He rose from the dead, but, as I said before, you have sent chosen and ordained men throughout all the world to proclaim that a godless and lawless heresy had sprung from one Jesus, a Galilæan deceiver, whom we crucified, **but his disciples stole him by night from the tomb, where he was laid when unfastened from the cross, and now deceive men by asserting that he has risen from the dead and ascended to heaven.**"

Comment: Of course, that only confirms they did not deny his existence

Comment: True. They very well could have said the disciples were talking about someone who didn't exist. But they didn't.

Comment: They also could have spread lies, which they didn't really do. I mean straight slander and propaganda. This suggests there was little motivation to attack Christian beliefs, compared to the motivation to attack Christians. "Belief" as basically a synonym for religion was a new phenomenon at the time, therefore, attacking it seems an odd thing to do.

Comment: Do you have a citation that belief=religion "at that time"?

Comment: @Mark The Roman government believed political stability hinged on the Imperial Cult. To Worship in the Imperial cult was proof of your loyalty to Rome. Belief in it was irrelevant. What Rome found offensive was not that Christians believed amazing things like the Resurrection, but that they utterly refused to engage in Imperial Cult worship. They were traitors. http://www.academia.edu/250713/Imperial_Cult_and_Christianity_How_and_to_What_Extent_Were_the_Imperial_Cult_and_Emperor_Worship_thought_to_Preserve_Stability_in_the_Roman_World

Comment: Perhaps lies and propaganda would have worked very well in squashing the new Christian cult but the Romans didn't think like that. The concept that a religion was a rubric of beliefs was foreign to them. They had the same problem with the Jews, but allowed them dispensation for at least a short while before destroying them in AD 70.

Comment: It took them over three hundred years to realize the power of belief, when Constantine instituted Christianity is the official and only legal religion. Then came the birth of the Roman Catholic Empire, arguably one of the most influential forces to have ever existed.

Comment: Before this time religion was what you did. After this time religion was what you believed.

Comment: [A spectacular book about the religions during the time of Jesus.](https://www.amazon.com/Man-Created-God-History-World/dp/1250044073) Every one of them that I can remember was about what you do not what you believed. The Jewish and Christian way of doing religion was very much a minority for a very long time.

Comment: Belief and "religion" are still two separate things. Simply put, religion is belief put into action

Comment: @Mark I'm not trying to define religion for modern practice. I'm trying to illuminate the fact that religion as we understand it today is quite different from religion as understood during the time of Jesus. I'm trying to point out that you're answering the question without knowledge of context.

Comment: James 1:27 reads: "Religion that God our Father accepts as pure and faultless is this: to look after orphans and widows in their distress and to keep oneself from being polluted by the world."

As I said, religion - in the time of Jesus - was belief put into action. I am fully aware of the context of my answer, thank you.

Comment: I contend that you are indeed not. -1